# Get item from json api flutter

Tags: json, parsing, flutter

How get 'ename' or 'job'  from this json format   eg.

```
{"items":[{"empno":7839,"ename":"KING","job":"PRESIDENT","mgr":null,....
```

For this json format use:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
```

eg. title: Text(posts[index]['name'])

What to do with 'items'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is `posts['items']['index']['ename']`,

**But I would recommend using the below approach,**

Create a model class from your response,
for example

```
class Welcome {
  String status;
  String error;
  int time;

  Welcome({this.status, this.error, this.time});

  factory Welcome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Welcome(
    status: json['status'],
      error: json['error'],
    time: json['time'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['status'] = this.status;
    data['error'] = this.error;
    data['time'] = this.time;
    return data;
  }

}
```

Then convert json to model like this,

```
Welcome welcome = Welcome.fromJson(dataConvertedToJSON);
```

Now you can get data by calling its getters,

```
welcome.status
```

For converting json to model u can use [this tool](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

Answer (score 1):

You can access it with a key "items"

```
Text(posts['items'][index]['job'])
```